# Cron Cache not working

Tags: caching, cron

I'm using the Cron Cache module to empty my cache tables especially the cache_form table who take 200Mo in 2 days ,but the probleme is that i notice that the module is not working anymore for few days ago .I'm thinking that it's the expire module maybe ??!!
Please any help ..
**NB:**
I launched the cron 2 times in 10 min (in 24 hours) and nothing happened on the database while i'm configurating my module to flash the cache tables every 24 hours

Comment: Link to same issue on modules issues tracker http://drupal.org/node/1878460

Comment: It's me the owner of that issue on drupal site, but as you see with no ansewer

Answer (score 0):

I Uninstalled the [expire](http://drupal.org/project/expire) module and the Cron cache module returns to work as usual